# Как правильно сделать эффект размытия объекта вне фокуса?

Tags: three.js, glsl, blur

Есть группа треугольников, если треугольник находится слишком близко к камере, то должен срабатывать эффект размытия:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать при помощи либы [glsl-fast-gaussian-blur](https://github.com/Jam3/glsl-fast-gaussian-blur). Размытие есть, но не большое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке увеличить границу размытия( через direction( 0.0, 3.0) ):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вершинный шейдер:

```
varying vec3 v_position;

void main() {

    v_position = position;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);

}
```

Фрагментый шейдер:

```
#pragma glslify: blur13 = require('glsl-fast-gaussian-blur')

uniform vec3 u_color;
uniform vec2 u_size;
uniform sampler2D u_image;

varying vec3 v_position;


vec4 blur(sampler2D, vec2, vec2, vec2);

void main(){

    vec2 texCoord = vec2( v_position.xy  /  u_size + 0.5);

    float blur_opacity = 0.0;
    // Размытие по горизонтали
    blur_opacity += blur13(u_image, texCoord, u_size, vec2( 0.0, 1.0)).a;
    // Размытие по вертикали
    blur_opacity += blur13(u_image, texCoord, u_size, vec2( 1.0, 0.0)).a;

    blur_opacity /= 2.0;

    gl_FragColor = vec4( u_color, blur_opacity ); 

}
```

Текстура:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто подскажет в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Есть пара примеров: https://threejs.org/examples/?q=post#webgl_postprocessing_dof и https://threejs.org/examples/?q=post#webgl_postprocessing_dof2

Comment: @prisoner849 спасибо, то что нужно)

Comment: Пожалуйста :) Рад помочь.